# Is a triangle waveform a type of pulse width modulation?

Tags: modulation

I'm confused as I have seen a triangle waveform referred to in terms of PWM but a triangle waveform does not actually modulate the pulse width.

Is a triangle waveform a type of pulse width modulation?

Comment: Are you asking if a triangle signal can be generated using PWM? Or if triangle waveform can be used as PWM-like carrier?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks … I removed my answer.

Comment: A real pulse width modulated signal can sometimes look triangular due to limitations in rise and fall times but, theoretically no.

Comment: Good question ...

Comment: Perhaps you've seen a triangle waveform *compared with* the analog input signal to create a PWM output? A triangle waveform generator block plus comparator block does the PWM trick.

Comment: In the early days of inverters (switch mode power supplies), a fixed frequency triangular waveform was used as the base switching frequency.  That analog waveform was compared to a fed-back version of the output - an error term.  The output of that comparator was the PWM signal that was used to drive the switching transistors.  What glen_geek said.

Comment: @SteveSh Not just the early days; this is still used as a didactic system for teaching how switching converters work (note: SMPS ≠ inverter!)

Comment: a pwm implies theoretically (but of course not actually) two levels.  Where a sine or triangle requires multiple levels or enough analog to make it not so much digital anymore.

Comment: @Hearth "(note: SMPS ≠ inverter!)".  Maybe in today's vernacular.  But the first SMPS I came across was called an inverter.  It took in 115 VAC (or 240 VAC) aircraft power, rectified it, did some sloppy filtering, then put it through a switching power supply to generate 5VDC @ 200 amps.  This is back in the early 70's.  Like I said, we called it an inverter.

Comment: @SteveSh Well, I guess technical jargon evolves just like the rest of language! I never knew that had changed meaning.

Comment: @Hearth - Well, to be fair, I'm not sure "inverter" was official in any sense.  That was just what we called our power supply.  In the early days of a technology, there is usually multiple terminology referring to the same thing.  Over time, some fall out of favor and one (or two) stick around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is a triangle waveform a type of pulse width modulation?

No, without pulse widths, there can't be a PWM.

Especially: Since the average of the triangle waveform is constant / can't be parameterized, there's nothing to *modulate*.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I though, it's really strange to see it referred to as a PWM.  I'm going to accept this as true unless someone gives a solid reason why it is false.

Answer (score 7):

The comparison of a triangle wave to a sine wave is a technique that has been used to generate a pwm waveform that simulates a sine wave.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> Is a **triangle** waveform a type of pulse width modulation?

Close .

**It is the Modulator** which has a **binary output by comparing an analog voltage**.

It is can also be done with a **sawtooth** waveform which is often harder to generate at high frequency.

[image]

Comment: I assume that using a triangle vs sawtooth wave generate PWM that is different, but still "close enough", that the average duty cycles are the same?